# How to generate font instances from an opentype variable font?

Tags: fonts, adobe, opentype

I have got an opentype 1.8 variable font,
but since it's not widely supported,
I wanna generate some instances from it
which could be used in common places.

AFDKO could process variable font.
How to do this with it?

Comment: I can't find much info on this yet, but it seems FontLab VI can generate a font from a variation. I tried this on a variable TTF, because it seems it cannot open variable OTFs yet. I'll keep researching.

Comment: AFDKO has an [experimental build](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/AFDKO-Variable-Font-Support.html) that supports it. (Reading that page, it seems enough familiarity with AFDKO is assumed.)

Comment: @usr2564301 Sorry but I'm not familiar with AFDKO (I just know it's powerful :). Could you give me a workable example on it?

Comment: No, sorry. Look for the full AFDKO documentation.

Comment: Protip: this is a rather niche question, so also ask this question over on http://typedrawers.com, which is a purely typography community. And if they give you an answer (which they usually do very quickly) you can post it here as well so that everybody wins =)

Comment: Before you do: are you allowed to? Fonts aren't free-for-all by default, can you say which font you have before we help you violate the legal constraints placed on that font? =)

Comment: Relevant post on TypeDrawers: [Generating static instances from variable font file](http://typedrawers.com/discussion/2565/generating-static-instances-from-variable-font-file)